# Why is my jquery animate() callback causing an overflow ? Recursion

Tags: javascript, jquery, recursion, callback, jquery-animate

I am using a recursive callback with the animate() jquery function.
However the page crashes everytime from the start.

```
var goingDown = true;

function animateChevron() {
        if (goingDown) {
            goingDown = !goingDown;
            $('#chevron').animate({'opacity': 1}, 500, animateChevron);
        }
        else {
            goingDown = !goingDown;
            $('#chevron').animate({'opacity': 0.1}, 500, animateChevron);
        }
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    animateChevron();
});
```

Thank you

**EDIT**: I want it to act in a loop: the chevron appears, then disappears, then appears again etc. As long as the user is on the page.

Comment: `animateChevron` is called in both the conditions - of course it is entering an infinite loop. What is it that you want to achieve ?

Comment: I want exactly this animation to be an inifinite loop, as long as the user is on the page. So the chevron appears, then diseappears, then appears etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 var speed=500; //in micro seconds
 setInterval(function(){
  
    var opacity=$('#chevron').css('opacity')<1 ? 1 : .1; 
  $('#chevron').animate({'opacity':opacity},speed);
    
 },speed);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="chevron">Chevron</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$('#chevron').animate({'opacity': 1}, {
  duration: 500, 
  complete: animateChevron
});
```

Also you can make this better

```
function animateChevron() {       
 $('#chevron').animate({'opacity': 1}, {
   duration: 500         
 }).animate({'opacity': 0.1}, {
  duration: 500,
  complete: animateChevron    
 });        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is recursing infinitely.

I changed it to add a parameter **goingDown**, which when true will cause the animation to hide the chevron, and set the state of a global variable **downState** to match **goingDown**.  I removed the recursion, you don't need it.

```js
var downState = null;

function animateChevron(goingDown) {
  if (!goingDown) {
        $('#chevron').animate({
      'opacity': 1
    }, 500);
  } else {
    $('#chevron').animate({
      'opacity': 0.1
    }, 500);
  }
  downState = goingDown;
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  animateChevron(true);
});
```

```css
#chevron {
font-size: 28px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="chevron">
&raquo;
</div>
```

Comment: The fact is that I want it to act as a loop, infinetly. The chevron appears, then disappears, then appears again etc.

Comment: Call it from within an interval - use setInterval and toggle the state passed in the parameter. Or use a .gif.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution due to the solution I offered first (can still be found at the bottom of this answer) didn't fit the needs of the asker.

According to the following question async callbacks will not cause any stack overflows.

[Will recursively calling a function from a callback cause a stack overflow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37971769/will-recursively-calling-a-function-from-a-callback-cause-a-stack-overflow/37971822#37971822)

```js
(function animateChevron() {
  // Chevron visible at this point
  $('#chevron').animate({'opacity': 0}, 500, () => {
    // Chevron invisible at this point
    $('#chevron').animate({'opacity': 1}, 500, animateChevron);
  });
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="chevron">Chevron</div>
```

---

I found a very neat solution right here at stackoverflow as alternative.

[How to make blinking/flashing text with css3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16344354/how-to-make-blinking-flashing-text-with-css3/16344389#16344389)

Code snippet by [Mr. Alien](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1542290/mr-alien):

```js
(function blink() { 
  $('#chevron').fadeOut(500).fadeIn(500, blink); 
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="chevron">Chevron</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, but I plan to make it moving as well, in a loop

Comment: I just updated my answer with another approach. I am not sure about what you need to do within the loop. Is `.animate()` enough? If so the updated approach might help.